# Does declaring variables and functions in same namespace get an error? [C++]

Tags: c++, namespaces

If I create a namespace Maths and use another library with a namespace named Maths, will I get an error for re-declaring a variable like PI or re-defining a function like add?

I ask because if I choose to not use namespaces, I should get an error for doing those things, right?

If I don't get an error using namespaces but I do when not using namespaces, isn't safer to just not use namespaces?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: "isn't safer to just not use namespaces" What if everyone follows that guideline? Also remember: ODR violations are ill-formed; no diagnostics required so be careful.

Comment: To answer your title question, no, that would make `namespace`s rather pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to test it myself:

```
//in file testnamespace.h
namespace test
{
  int t = 1;
  void fooo(){};
}

//in file testnamespace2.h
namespace test
{
  int t=10000;
  void fooo(){int x = -2;}
}

//in file test.cpp
#include "testnamespace.h"
#include "testnamespace2.h"
int main()
{
  int ayyyeee = test::t;
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

This gives an error for redefinition,multiple initialization.

All I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, **namespace** must be `global` and In different `namespace` you can have `same` function or variable, but in `same namespace` you can't have same variable declaration twice.

```
    namespace A {
            int i=10;
            char i ='a';/** is not valid **/
            void print() {
             ...
            }
    }
    namespace B {
        float i = 1.5; /** valid **/
        void print() { /** valid **/
             ...
        }
    }
```

In above example in `namespace A` and `B` you have `i` of `int` type and `i` of `float` type respectively which is `valid` but In `namespace A` itself you can't have  variable `i` of different types (considered as re-declaration)

Comment: If I had a separate file with namespace A {int i = -234; void print(){};} Would I get an error? (With your code in a separate file)

Comment: both file can have same `namespace` called `A`, but inside both `namespace` if  variable name are same, the it will  be `error` of like multiple definition